# Not understanding arguments of a new function as argument

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial to make an upload system for images.

Now the following function is used for uploading, and it uses the external module **formidable**

```
function upload(response, request) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log("about to parse");
  form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
    console.log("parsing done");

    fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png",
      function(error) {
        if (error) {
          fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
          fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
        }
      });
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write("received image:<br/>");
      response.write("<img src='/show' />");
      response.end();
  });
}
```

form.parse takes 2 arguments, **request** and a **new function** but the new function takes 3 new arguments.

I can't seem to understand it. Where do these 3 new arguments come from? Has it to do with the external library or do I not understand JavaScript correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a callback function expected by the external library. You should really go read about JS basics. http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/ and then find the source code of the Formidable which implements the ``parse`` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.parse` take 2 args, second arg is function called `callback`. Callback get arguments from `form.parse` implementation.

Let explain on more simple example:

```
function foo(callback) {
    var arg1 = 10;
    var arg2 = 'string';
    var arg3 = false;

    // call function with args
    callback(arg1, arg2, arg3);
};


function callback(num, str, bool) {
    // we get args from foo implementation
    console.log(num);
    console.log(str);
    console.log(bool);
}

foo(callback);
```

In `foo` code we call `callback` with 3 args. Now we can use them in `callback` function

Answer (score 1):

The way to think of this is that `form.parse` takes two parameters - the first indicated by request and the second a function. This second function is being passed as a parameter to `form.parse` so that it can be invoked by that function at some point.

It might be clearer for you to see it written like this instead (it is equivalent but, arguably, clearer):

```
function upload(response, request) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
  var process_request = function(error, fields, files) {
    console.log("parsing done");

    fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png",
      function(error) {
        if (error) {
          fs.unlink("/tmp/test.png");
          fs.rename(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");
        }
      });
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write("received image:<br/>");
      response.write("<img src='/show' />");
      response.end();
  };

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log("about to parse");
  form.parse(request, process_request );
}
```

In this case, we've declared a function `process_request` and passing it to `form.parse`. It will be "called back" at some point by that function and it will be called (most likely, though not guaranteed) with 3 parameters when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument passed to the form.parse method as the second argument is a callback function. It is called by form.parse after the form has been parsed. The values for the arguments of the callback function come from the form.parse method.